# What's wrong with this array declaration?

Tags: c++, pointers

I created this array this array inside a function, with the variable MODEL_VERTEX_NUM initialized @ runtime, which, I guess, is the sticking point here.

```
loat model_vertices [][]= new float [MODEL_VERTEX_NUM][3];
```

I got the following errors:

```
1>.\GLUI_TEMPLATE.cpp(119) : error C2087: 'model_vertices' : missing subscript
1>.\GLUI_TEMPLATE.cpp(119) : error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'float (*)[3]' to 'float [][1]'
```

I realize that when I do:

```
float model_vertices *[]= new float [MODEL_VERTEX_NUM][3];
```

The compiler lets this pass, but I wanna understand what's wrong with the previous declaration.

So, what's wrong with the `[][]` declaration?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For a two-dimensional array `a[X][Y]` the compiler needs to know `Y` to generate code to access the array, so you need to change your code to

```
float (*model_vertices) [3] = new float [2][3];
```

If you have an array of type `T` `a[X][Y]` and want to access `a[x][y]` that is equivalent to accessing `*(((T*)(&a[0][0])) + x*Y + y)`. As you can see the compiler needs to know `Y` but not `X` to generate code for accessing the array.

Comment: Doing what you say (float model_vertices [] [3]= new float [MODEL_VERTEX_NUM][3];)I got this: error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'float (*)[3]' to 'float [][3]'

Comment: Sorry, fixed the code now. This compiles: "float (*model_vertices) [3]= new float [2][3];"